# What is correct: загон or Закон

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, глаголы

In song "Где я!" lyrics is word **загон** and **закон**. Why this word have two different form?

```
Мне не звони на телефон, не за неуплату он отключен.
Ты знаешь, в жизни бывает и не такой загон.
Закон джунглей моих: лишь дело, меньше слов.
Знаешь, я даже не парюсь, совет вам да любовь.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two different words. The word загон is from teenage slang, it comes from verb [загоняться](http://www.slovonovo.ru/term/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), to think a lot about something not deserving that, to have the mind occupied by an unimportant problrem.

At the same time закон means law.

Comment: Interesting, but now I can't understand whole sentence. What does it meas? Ты знаешь, в жизни бывает и не такой загон.

Comment: Something like, "You know, in life there can be a bigger pounding." (play on words, too, pound as "enclosure" and "pound" as "hit repeatedly).

Comment: @Michal "you know there happen greater "idea fix"-es in life". Anyway are you serious to find any meaning in rap?

Comment: I think your is not complete. загон is a common word that means corral (i.e. corral for cows). And both words загоняться and загон (that 'teenage' slang) come from it. Please update.

Comment: @Mikant I very much doubt they come from it.